# In a for loop, update the value of the iteration variable of the external loop with the output of the internal loop

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

I am working in R.

I have two for loops nested one into another. Assume we have `j` as iteration variable.

When the inner loop is called, it outputs a new value of `j`, which the has to be used as iteration variable of the main loop.

Let me provide you with a practical example:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)

for (j in 1:length(a)){
    if (a[j] > 2){
        j <- 5
    }
}
```

in this case, when the inner loop is called (i.e. when `a[j] > 2`), I want to update the value of `j` in a way that becomes disconnetted to the sequence `j in 1:length(a)`.

In fact, in the example above I would like to have `j = 5` as iteration variable of the external loop for `a[3] = 3`, instead of `j = 3`.

Of course, this is a toy example. All I want to do is to be able to update the value of the iteration variable of the external loop with the output of the inner loop. Is it possible?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `while` statement:

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4)
j <- 1
while (j <=length(a)){
  if (a[j] > 2){
    j <- 5
  }
  print(j)
  j <- j + 1
}

[1] 1
[1] 2
[1] 5
```